how to pass object to _blob.html.erb
I use Action Text and Action Storage. Rails make _blob.html.erb file:
`
`<figure class="attachment attachment--<%= blob.representable? ? "preview" : "file" %> attachment--<%= blob.filename.extension %>">
  <% if blob.representable? %>
     <%= link_to (image_tag (blob.representation(resize_to_limit: local_assigns[:in_gallery] ? [ 800, 600 ] : [ 1024, 768 ]))), news_path(@new) %>
  <% end %>

  <figcaption class="attachment__caption">
    <% if caption = blob.try(:caption) %>
      <%= caption %>
    <% else %>
      <span class="attachment__name"><%= blob.filename %></span>
      <span class="attachment__size"><%= number_to_human_size blob.byte_size %></span>
    <% end %>
  </figcaption>
</figure>``

In 4 line I link_to for images.All images displays on index page for path /news (model name is new). I want to see show page when I press link.  But I don't know how to make @new object to create /news/id path. I understand I need make @new object in index action. Now I make @new object in index action like this:
def index
    @news = News.all
    @new = News.first 
end

But All images have same id and when I click to links I go same show view. Where and how I need make @new objects?
I dont't try anything because I don't know to think.
